# dialogflow quick reply for Facebook client

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

When I'm trying to send a response from Node app to Dialogflow using webhook for Facebook messenger client.

Trying to send a quick reply to the Facebook client, however, it is not working and getting the bellow error.

**Error: Reply string required by Suggestion constructor**

Any help will be appreciated.

```
const {Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
agent.add(new Suggestion().setReply('test reply from NodeApp'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to update the version of **dialogflow-fulfillment** package in the *package.json* file in the inline editor to ^0.6.1 which is the latest one.

Then, I think you can just send quick replies using the statement:

```
agent.add(new Suggestion(`sample reply`));
```

Please remember there should have a text response before the replies for Facebook to accept the response object.

Below is a snippet that may help you better.

```
const {Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
agent.add(`This is quick reply.`);
agent.add(new Suggestion(`option 1`));
agent.add(new Suggestion(`option 2`));
```

The above way will work if you are using the ***Dialogflow Inline Editor** as the fulfillment*.

If not (i.e, opt to have your own deployment/development environment), you have to send the quick replies as custom payloads within the fulfillment code. (Here also, you have to upgrade the **dialogflow-fulfillment** package first)

Here is a sample code snippet:

```
const {Payload} = require("dialogflow-fulfillment")
var payload = {
  "facebook": {
    "text": "Welcome to my agent!",
    "quick_replies": [
      {
        "content_type": "text",
        "payload": "reply1",
        "title": "reply 1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
agent.add(new Payload(agent.UNSPECIFIED, payload, {rawPayload: true, sendAsMessage: true}))
```

Hope these will work for you.